# Changing order of the words in line

Tags: sed

I'm trying to print a file with students' names.

```
muhaz:x:6541:113:AhmmedMuhaz Mohammed Kunhi Mulleria:/home/students/muhaz:/bin/bash
```

I need my output to be like that:

```
muhaz:x:6541:113:Mulleria Mohammed Kunhi AhmmedMuhaz:/home/students/muhaz:/bin/bash
```

This is what I've tried but it does not work at all.

```
cat /etc/passwd | tail -n 20 | sed -r 's/.*[[:alpha:]]+([[:blank:]][[:alpha:]]+)*.*/\3\2\1/'
```

How should the command look and what is wrong?

Entry file:

```
rovshan:x:6532:113:Rovshan Ahmadli:/home/students/rovshan:/bin/bash
smith_63:x:6533:113:Smith Pataraprasitpon:/home/students/smith_63:/bin/bash
rashad:x:6534:113:Rashad Mahmudov:/home/students/rashad:/bin/bash
dilgamsh:x:6535:113:Dilgam Sharifov:/home/students/dilgamsh:/bin/bash
nlk_ns:x:6536:113:Nurlan Zhangali:/home/students/nlk_ns:/bin/bash
karpwiol:x:6537:113:WK:/home/students/karpwiol:/bin/bash
yigit123:x:6538:113:Mustafa Yigit Ersoz:/home/students/yigit123:/bin/bash
orxan123:x:6539:113:Orkhan Abiyev:/home/students/orxan123:/bin/bash
valiyev:x:6540:113:rufat valiyev:/home/students/valiyev:/bin/bash
muhaz:x:6541:113:AhmmedMuhaz Mohammed Kunhi Mulleria:/home/students/muhaz:/bin/bash
fatihebr:x:6542:113:Fatih Ocal:/home/students/fatihebr:/bin/bash
mrgo_g:x:6543:113:margarita gagaeva:/home/students/mrgo_g:/bin/bash
chrisd48:x:6544:113:Christian Hibestu:/home/students/chrisd48:/bin/bash
qwertinx:x:6545:113:Jakub Kaczmarczyk:/home/students/qwertinx:/bin/bash
grrronek:x:6546:113:Katarzyna Gro▒ska:/home/students/grrronek:/bin/bash
shahin:x:6547:113:Shahin Mehrabov:/home/students/shahin:/bin/bash
soufroud:x:6548:113:sofiane bouzroud:/home/students/soufroud:/bin/bash
jtrojak0:x:6549:113:Joanna Trojak:/home/students/jtrojak0:/bin/bash
jtrojak1:x:6550:113:Joanna Trojak:/home/students/jtrojak1:/bin/bash
markam:x:6551:113:Marcel Kami▒ski:/home/students/markam:/bin/bash
```

What I'm trying to achieve is for example:

```
shahin:x:6547:113:Mehrabov Shahin:/home/students/shahin:/bin/bash
jtrojak1:x:6550:113:Trojak Joanna:/home/students/jtrojak1:/bin/bash
yigit123:x:6538:113:Ersoz Yigit Mustafa:/home/students/yigit123:/bin/bash
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit, but you don't tell us what you are trying to do. How can we go from `AhmmedMuhaz Mohammed Kunhi Mulleria` to `Mulleria Mohammed Kunhi AhmmedMuhaz`? What should happen to `Mustafa Yigit Ersoz`? Should it be `Ersoz Yigit Mustafa`? Or maybe `Yigit Ersoz Mustafa`? Or something else? And how can we know?

Comment: Is it enough now?

Comment: I hope that those login names and full names are invented. But unfortunately, the character encoding artifacts suggest they're not. Also assuming that all people/cultures follow the first name, middle name[s], last name convention is gross; people's names are better left as they're used.

Comment: I went into a same issue a few weeks ago. If this can help as a starting point, because my case was not as complex as your: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1204142/swap-parts-of-filenames Try out to mix non-greedy and greedy matches using e.g. `rename`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this with GNU `sed`, assuming the string is unique, if not, comment on it:

```
sed -E 's/:(\w+) (\w+) (\w+) (\w+):/:\4 \2 \3 \1:/' file
```

Output:

```
muhaz:x:6541:113:Mulleria Mohammed Kunhi AhmmedMuhaz:/home/students/muhaz:/bin/bash
```

Comment: you get 20 lines with 20 names, sometimes there's only one first and second name, sometimes there's more so this is gonna work only in that exact case

Comment: @MartynaMichalska Welcome! Could you post the entire file, and tell us what pattern exactly is you are looking for? It's the last names at the beginning? If so, what happens if there are two last names?

Comment: @MartynaMichalska that's the kind of detail you need to include in your question. We can't know what you need. The more detail you give us, the better your chances of getting a useful answer. So please edit your question and explain exactly how we can know what to do.

Comment: I added those 20 lines that need to be modified

Answer (score 0):

For structured data, you may find that a tool such as Awk is a better fit, ex.

```
$ echo 'muhaz:x:6541:113:AhmmedMuhaz Mohammed Kunhi Mulleria:/home/students/muhaz:/bin/bash' | awk -F: '
    BEGIN {OFS=FS} 
    {n=split($5,a,/ /); $5 = a[n]; for(i=2;i<n;i++) $5 = $5 " " a[i]; $5 = $5 " " a[1]}
    {print}
  '
muhaz:x:6541:113:Mulleria Mohammed Kunhi AhmmedMuhaz:/home/students/muhaz:/bin/bash
```

Comment: thank you but unfortunately I need to do it with the use of sed

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU sed we can do it as:

```
$ sed -r '
    s/:/\n/4;s//\n/4
    s/\n(\S+)(.*\s)(\S+)\n/:\3\2\1:/
    y/\n/:/
' file
```

Mark out the fifth field by means of a unique marker guaranteed to not be found.

Then within that portion barricaded by the markers on both sides, flip the first and last words.

In the event that the step above didn't go through, say it had just one name, as people in Central Asia will be for example, then remove those markers.

sed default prints the pattern space.

Answer (score 0):

With GNU awk for gensub():

```
$ gawk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=":"} {$5=gensub(/^(\S+)((\s+\S+)*\s+)(\S+)$/,"\\4\\2\\1",1,$5)} 1' file
rovshan:x:6532:113:Ahmadli Rovshan:/home/students/rovshan:/bin/bash
smith_63:x:6533:113:Pataraprasitpon Smith:/home/students/smith_63:/bin/bash
rashad:x:6534:113:Mahmudov Rashad:/home/students/rashad:/bin/bash
dilgamsh:x:6535:113:Sharifov Dilgam:/home/students/dilgamsh:/bin/bash
nlk_ns:x:6536:113:Zhangali Nurlan:/home/students/nlk_ns:/bin/bash
karpwiol:x:6537:113:WK:/home/students/karpwiol:/bin/bash
yigit123:x:6538:113:Ersoz Yigit Mustafa:/home/students/yigit123:/bin/bash
orxan123:x:6539:113:Abiyev Orkhan:/home/students/orxan123:/bin/bash
valiyev:x:6540:113:valiyev rufat:/home/students/valiyev:/bin/bash
muhaz:x:6541:113:Mulleria Mohammed Kunhi AhmmedMuhaz:/home/students/muhaz:/bin/bash
fatihebr:x:6542:113:Ocal Fatih:/home/students/fatihebr:/bin/bash
mrgo_g:x:6543:113:gagaeva margarita:/home/students/mrgo_g:/bin/bash
chrisd48:x:6544:113:Hibestu Christian:/home/students/chrisd48:/bin/bash
qwertinx:x:6545:113:Kaczmarczyk Jakub:/home/students/qwertinx:/bin/bash
grrronek:x:6546:113:Gro▒ska Katarzyna:/home/students/grrronek:/bin/bash
shahin:x:6547:113:Mehrabov Shahin:/home/students/shahin:/bin/bash
soufroud:x:6548:113:bouzroud sofiane:/home/students/soufroud:/bin/bash
jtrojak0:x:6549:113:Trojak Joanna:/home/students/jtrojak0:/bin/bash
jtrojak1:x:6550:113:Trojak Joanna:/home/students/jtrojak1:/bin/bash
markam:x:6551:113:Kami▒ski Marcel:/home/students/markam:/bin/bash
```

With a sed that takes a `-E` argument to support EREs (e.g. GNU or OSX/BSD sed):

```
$ sed -E 's/(([^:]*:){4})([^[:space:]:]+)(([[:space:]]+[^[:space:]:]+)*[[:space:]]+)([^[:space:]:]+)/\1\6\4\3/' file
rovshan:x:6532:113:Ahmadli Rovshan:/home/students/rovshan:/bin/bash
smith_63:x:6533:113:Pataraprasitpon Smith:/home/students/smith_63:/bin/bash
rashad:x:6534:113:Mahmudov Rashad:/home/students/rashad:/bin/bash
dilgamsh:x:6535:113:Sharifov Dilgam:/home/students/dilgamsh:/bin/bash
nlk_ns:x:6536:113:Zhangali Nurlan:/home/students/nlk_ns:/bin/bash
karpwiol:x:6537:113:WK:/home/students/karpwiol:/bin/bash
yigit123:x:6538:113:Ersoz Yigit Mustafa:/home/students/yigit123:/bin/bash
orxan123:x:6539:113:Abiyev Orkhan:/home/students/orxan123:/bin/bash
valiyev:x:6540:113:valiyev rufat:/home/students/valiyev:/bin/bash
muhaz:x:6541:113:Mulleria Mohammed Kunhi AhmmedMuhaz:/home/students/muhaz:/bin/bash
fatihebr:x:6542:113:Ocal Fatih:/home/students/fatihebr:/bin/bash
mrgo_g:x:6543:113:gagaeva margarita:/home/students/mrgo_g:/bin/bash
chrisd48:x:6544:113:Hibestu Christian:/home/students/chrisd48:/bin/bash
qwertinx:x:6545:113:Kaczmarczyk Jakub:/home/students/qwertinx:/bin/bash
grrronek:x:6546:113:Gro▒ska Katarzyna:/home/students/grrronek:/bin/bash
shahin:x:6547:113:Mehrabov Shahin:/home/students/shahin:/bin/bash
soufroud:x:6548:113:bouzroud sofiane:/home/students/soufroud:/bin/bash
jtrojak0:x:6549:113:Trojak Joanna:/home/students/jtrojak0:/bin/bash
jtrojak1:x:6550:113:Trojak Joanna:/home/students/jtrojak1:/bin/bash
markam:x:6551:113:Kami▒ski Marcel:/home/students/markam:/bin/bash
```